# iFrame works in FF and Edge (old version) or IE but not in Chrome or Newer Edge

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

I've got an iFrame

```
<iframe border="0" src="https://catalogportal?clientId=xxxx&clientSecret=yyyy&refreshToken=kkk&HOOK_URL=http://myurl" height="720px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

which works in ie11, Firefox (even latest FF), Edge (previous versions) but not in Chrome or newever version of Edge.
With the newer version it's like if the parameters are not sent and therefore I get a login error... The error message which is displayed is "xxx redirected you too many times".

Anybody know what the issue could be?
Thanks

Comment: same issue here. anybody with a fix?

Comment: Check the samesite cookie policy (lax, none). That has changed in Chrome and Edge (latest version). It was the issue with me